# Microsoft Edge 14/15 caching issue with JS

Tags: javascript, caching, microsoft-edge

The issue is with a eCommerce website for the checkout flow. All the JS and other assets are being cached at the browser level.

I’ve tried adding the `<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">` and

```
<%
response.setHeader(“Cache-Control","no-cache”);
response.setHeader(“Pragma","no-cache”);
response.setDateHeader ("Expires", -1);
%>
```

but this doesn’t seem to solve or help with the issue. When I checked the debugger tab in developer tools, I can see the scripts being duplicated (for example: I can see login.js from cache and also from the server). FYI, we are using DWR3.

Looking for a solution for this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Regards,
Kousik.

Comment: Are you certain this behavior is only occurring in Edge?  Is this response object for the page itself or the asset files in some kind of http handler?

Comment: @JaromandaX I also tried <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma” CONTENT="no-cache">

Yes, this is only happening on edge. And the response object is not for the page itself but for asset files

Comment: sorry, I should've tried to edit the question earlier - what you tried should be visible now :p

Comment: about:flags> Enable localhost loopback... close and restart edge for the changes to take affect. are you using the visual studio IIS express or localhost IIS? Also check that you do not have Always refresh from server enabled on the Networking tab of the Edge dev tool.